# How to set up Livepatch on Ubuntu One?

Tags: login, ubuntu-one

I'm an old unix fellow that cannot get "Ubuntu One" to work from my Linux laptop. I'm hoping to get past that in order to use "LivePatch".

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1444327/edit) to clearly describe the problem that you are encountering. "Cannot get XYZ to work" is a bit too vague to offer useful advice. Which section or step has you stuck? What page are you seeing or what output has you puzzled?

Comment: If you routinely shutdown your computer once a day or so, there is no real advantage to running Livepatch. It is helpful for servers or other devices that run all the time.

Answer (score 1):

To set up Livepatch on Ubuntu, you will need to have a Ubuntu One account and have the Livepatch service enabled on your system.

There is a comprehensive guide you need to follow :

https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch